# Help To Identify Electrical Connector (possibly JST)

Tags: batteries, connector, identification

Does anyone know what type of connector this is with the 11 wires in it please? I'm after the male version.

I thought JST GH but it looks like probably not...

[image]

[image]

EDIT: I only have the female receptor. Here it is...

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's a lot easier to ID connectors if you have a profile / cross section view. Could you add another picture?

Comment: Unfortunately @bathMarm0t they are the only photo's I have

Comment: I've just added a couple of new photos @bathMarm0t